# JRuby rpm for Centos 5.3?

Tags: java, centos, ruby, centos-5

Has anybody built a JRuby RPM for Centos 5.3?  I know that JRuby can be just 'dropped in' and it will work on Centos 5.3, but I would like an RPM because it can be distributed, installed etc. easily using existing rpm mechanisms.

So, has anybody attempted this? Please share!

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.frameos.org/2010/10/15/installing-jruby-and-trinidad-in-framoscentos/

Yum install jruby instead of Trinidad.